# How to receive data on a websocket, and use it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket

Since I'm still fairly new to Javascript (and Node.js and React), I've got another question for the experts here. I'm trying to get some client/server communication set up, and while I think I have data sending set up for this, I'm not sure that I have the receiving part correct. Best as I can figure, this either isn't returning in time for me to pass back to calling code, or I'm not getting the order of operations correct. My code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, WebSocket } from 'react';

const URL_WEB_SOCKET = 'wss://localhost:5000/ws';
const URL_WEB_LOGIN = 'wss://localhost:5000/ws';
let socketMessage = "";

function useWebSockets (message, isControl) {
  let data = "";
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const websocket = new WebSocket(isControl ? URL_WEB_LOGIN : URL_WEB_SOCKET);
    
    websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
      socketMessage = event.data.toString();

      // first attempt
      //data = event.data.toString();//JSON.parse(event.data);
      //return event.data;
    }

    websocket.onopen = () => {
      websocket.send(message);
    }
  }, [])
}

export function getData(message) {
  const ws = new useWebSockets(message, false);
  return ws.data;
}

export function Login(message) {
  let ws = new useWebSockets(message, true);
  return ws.data;
}
```

This is all in one file. I'm calling the Login and getData functions from another file, and they should be returning whatever data is passed back by the socket. However, I'm getting undefined errors. Do I have this set up correctly? Thanks.

**Update**
I have updated my code to the above, and I now can get back the websocket itself, but still no data (It's always blank).  I think my code here is mostly correct, but from what I know about programming, I wonder if Javascript is dealing with this in an asynchronous manner and needing to wait for the onmessage to trigger before I can read the results. The server is sending data back fine, so how can I get the data and push it back through the Login and GetData functions to the calling code?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're actually returning anything inside the hook.

Comment: That what previous comment said, and also `websocket.close()` never gets executed because it is written after `return data` and [`return` statement ends function execution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: @Aleksandar Ok, since I've been getting conflicting information on how this is supposed to be able to work, I'm going to make a couple of guesses here.  First, I'm guessing that I need to return the data from inside the onmessage?  Is my way of reading this from the getData and Login functions correct?  Second, I was under the impression that the assignment gets scheduled, so the return  statement followed by the websocket.close would have worked.  From comments, I'm guessing that was incorrect.

Comment: which react version are you using? I did not know you could import `import {WebSocket} from "react"`

Comment: @Yilmaz using 18.2.0

Comment: I get this error from the same version: `Module '"react"' has no exported member 'WebSocket'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the "useWebSockets" function doesn't return anything, so when you try to use it to get data in getData and Login, it will always return undefined.

Moreover you're trying to use "useEffect" to set up the WebSocket connection and receive data, but "useEffect" is designed for **side effects** and should not be used to return data. Instead, you should use the **useState** hook to store the data received from the WebSocket connection, and update the state when you receive data.

try this approach instead:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const URL_WEB_SOCKET = 'wss://localhost:5000/ws';
const URL_WEB_LOGIN = 'wss://localhost:5000/ws';

export function WebSocketComponent({ isControl, message }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const websocket = new WebSocket(isControl ? URL_WEB_LOGIN : URL_WEB_SOCKET);
    
    websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
      setData(event.data.toString());
    }

    websocket.onopen = () => {
      websocket.send(message);
    }

    return () => {
      websocket.close();
    }
  }, [isControl, message]);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}

export function getData(message) {
  return <WebSocketComponent isControl={false} message={message} />;
}

export function Login(message) {
  return <WebSocketComponent isControl={true} message={message} />;
}
```

- React [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook
- React [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook
- MDN[WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) API documentation

Comment: This is great, and really moves me forward.  I've tried looking at the Mozilla stuff there, and am not sure I fully understand it, but it does get data back.  Now I just need to figure out how to extract the data as it's JSON and has a whole bunch of different stuff getting used a level up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ‍‍‍`websocket.onclose` in front end, and close the websocket on the backend side.

You declared data `const data = "";` as a String type,while `JSON.parse(event.data);` returns Object.
you should use `let` or declare it inside `websocket.onmessage` function.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, and have made adjustments locally to my code.  However, I'm still not sure that I'm using the useWebSockets correctly in the two functions below.  Do you have any further advice about how I'm using it?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a backend developer and I don't know anything about React,I just had a question, why do you have two variables with different names and the same values.`URL_WEB_SOCKET`, `URL_WEB_LOGIN`

Comment: Because I'm using them that way in the test environment, they'll be changed to different values later for production.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `https` in localhost ?
if not , try `ws://` for http

Comment: Also try changing `localhost` to IP of the server `ws://192.xxx.x.xxx`